# Why am I getting "corrupted double-linked list" error?

Tags: c, linked-list, corruption

## The program

I am writing a program in C that reads in a document of polynomial coefficients and can evaluate the roots of the polynomials.

In one of my functions I am attempting to read through the text file, and create a list of "polynomials". Polynomials are defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int nterms;       /* number of terms */
    double complex *polyCoef;  /* coefficients    */
} polynomial;
```

The text files are in the following format, where each line represents a polynomial and each number represents a coefficient:

```
1     0     0     0     2    -1
16    70  -169  -580    75
1     0     4     0    -5
0    -9     3     5    -3
5    -4     3    -2     0
1.0   -3.4    5.4531   -4.2077    1.5092   -0.2030
```

---

## The Problem

I am getting some odd behavior in my implementation attempt. 
With the following code, I get

> *** Error in `./hw6': corrupted double-linked list: 0x0000000000a1c240 ***

```
    PolyFile = fopen(argv[2], "r"); 

    if(NULL == PolyFile){   /* If the file fails to open */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Input file '%s' not found\n", argv[2]); 
        return(-1); 
    }

    /****** Read in the polynomials *************/
    polynomials = malloc(sizeof(polynomial*) * size); /* Initialize */

    if(polynomials == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s %i: Could not allocate memory\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        exit(-99); 
    }

    /* Read all of the data from the file */
    while(fgets(String, MAX_STR_LEN, PolyFile)) {
        strLen = strlen(String); /* Determine size of line */

   /* Ensure that the line is not too long */
        if(strLen <= MAX_STR_LEN){
            /* Create the polynomial */
            p = (polynomial*)malloc(sizeof(polynomial)); 

            token = strtok(String, " ");

            while(token){
                coefficients[coeffCount] = token; 
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                coeffCount++;   
            } 
            createPoly(p, coeffCount); 

            /* Set p->polyCoef to the reverse of coefficients */            
            for(int lcv = 0; lcv <= coeffCount - 1; lcv++){

                p->polyCoef[lcv] = atof(coefficients[coeffCount - lcv - 1]) + 0.00*I; 
            }
            coeffCount = 0; 

            polynomials[size] = p;
            printf("P->NTERMS: %i\n", p->nterms); 
            size++; 

        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s %i: Line too long. Polynomial ignored\n",
                        __FILE__, __LINE__); 
        }

    }
    fclose(PolyFile); 
    /**************************/
    for(int j = 0; j <= size - 1; j++){
        printf("J: %i\n", j); 
        printf("IN FOR LOOP: %i\n", (polynomials[j])->nterms); 
        // printPoly(polynomials[j]); 
        printf("\n"); 
    }
```

. . .

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Creates a polynomial data structure with nterms.  This allocates storage
  for the actual polynomial.

  Where: polynomial *p       - Pointer to polynomial data structure to create
         unsigned int nterms - The number of elements to create
  Returns: nothing
  Errors:  prints an error and exits
---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void createPoly(polynomial *p, unsigned int nterms){
  int lcv; /* loop control variable */

  /* Create a polynomial struct */
  p->nterms = nterms; 
  p->polyCoef = (double complex*)malloc(sizeof(double complex)*nterms); 

  /* Error out if problem with malloc */
  if(p->polyCoef == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s %i:Error allocating memory\n", __FILE__, __LINE__); 
    exit(1); 
  }

  /* Set the coefficients to 0 */
  for(lcv = 0; lcv < nterms; lcv++){
    (p->polyCoef)[lcv] = 0.00 + 0.00*I; 
  }
}
```

If I remove the `fclose(PolyFile);`, the code continues, but debug printing shows that `polynomials[0]->nterms` is equal to a random, changing, very large number.  I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you debug such problems. It should only take a few minutes to learn and run and can point you directly to the problem most of the time.

Comment: @kaylum does that suggest that it is a memory leak issue?

Comment: No, more likely a memory corruption.

Comment: No, it's probably not a leak - you probably overwrite the heap at some point and corrupt heap structures. You'll have to debug it to find it.

Comment: Okay, I'll try out valgrind!

Comment: `polynomials[size] = p;` is almost certainly wrong. If you allocate `size` entries, then `size` itself is not a valid index and will result in memory corruption. And I don't know why you are doing `size++` since you have already allocated a fixed array with `size` entries. Perhaps you meant to use a different variable for the index.

Comment: You're right, that's where the issue is. I want `polynomials` to be the final size, but when I allocate `size` is 0.  I'll have to figure out how to get around that

Comment: Where `coeffCount` is initialized to 0 before `while(token)` ? This variable is only set to 0 after...

Comment: @tibsar Glad you are on the right track. As a Stackoverflow usage note, please ensure that you always post an [MCVE]. This is a classic example of why that is needed - there is no way we could have known that `size` is 0 (though many of us would have suspected based on your code). It'll save everyone, not least yourself, a lot of time if you always provide an MCVE.

Comment: How is `coefficients` declared? `lcv <= coeffCount - 1;` can be written as `lcv < coeffCount;` BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because at the time of the initialization of `polynomials`, `size` was equal to 0:

```
polynomials = malloc(sizeof(polynomial*) * size);
```

This was fixed by allocating the proper size, using the number of lines in the file.